# Python - Dictionary and in

Tags: python, if-statement

And sorry for the bad title-name, couldn't really figure out any good one.

I'm having a problem I can't solve. I've tried all sort of things to find the problem, but I can't seem to solve it.

http://www.codesend.com/view/62a8ede9843cb4c63196285c104f7bd7/
Here's my code.

I've made a dictionary out of a file I read out from (works correctly, tested and printed out etc). I then take an input by the user, made into a string. Then I run checkData(), which is supposed to look if any of the letters in the txt is in the dictionary. For the sake of solving my problem, let's use the non-commented checkData(), which basically just prints if everything is there or not.

My problem is that no matter what I have as an input, everything exists (which it does not). I've tried using random symbols, such as •Ωıéœµ•üΩµé, but it still says everything exists. The loop works perfectly and prints out 'is within', which means that the txt[i] is in dictMorse or dictTxt. But the "if txt[i] in dictMorse or dictTxt:" doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question don't link to it.

Comment: There is too much code, and it shouldn't be posted on an external site. Cut it down to the *minimum* example that demonstrates the problem, and add it into your question.

Comment: I will in future posts, just did this on a whim without thinking too much after not solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
if txt[i] in dictMorse or dictTxt:
```

is equivalent to

```
if (txt[i] in dictMorse) or dictTxt:
```

This condition will always be true when `dictTxt` is nonempty.

You probably mean:

```
if txt[i] in dictMorse or txt[i] in dictTxt:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        if txt[i] in dictMorse or dictTxt:
```

`x in y or z` is parsed as `(x in y) or z`. A nonempty dict is treated as true. You want the following:

```
        if txt[i] in dictMorse or txt[i] in dictTxt:
```

Comment: Even if it were parsed "the other way", it still wouldn't mean what OP wants it to mean. Attempts like this are taking an informal view of logic that just isn't compatible with programming.